# Firebase 2nd developer unable to edit Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

My group is using firebase, but we keep running into an error.
I created the project, and when I run this code, I am able to edit the Realtime Database. However, my friend, using a different account and laptop, runs the same code but is unable to do so.

```
FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;

mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

mFirebaseInstance.getReference().child("users").child(username).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot != null && dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
            // username is already taken
        } else {
            // username is valid
            User user = new User(username, email, "1231231234", password);
            System.out.println("hello");
            mDatabase.child(DatabaseKeys.userKey).child(username).setValue(user);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("cancelled");
    }
});
```

I have made him an owner along with me.

This is what we have done at this point:

- Used print statements to isolate the problem to the POST and GET request. It successfully enters a button in which this code resides, but doesn't run the code.
- We added `onTaskFailure` and `onTaskComplete` listeners, and made them print stuff, but they didn't do anything, giving us the impression that it was stuck
- We tried it on another friend's laptop (3rd person in a group) and it WORKED. His laptop successfully sent data to the real-time database, using the exact same code.
- At this point we're just suspecting it's a laptop issue. For information, the laptop with the issue is a MacBook Air, running on Big Sur, with the newest version of Android Studio.

If this is just a mac issue, what are some possible problems that are being caused and ways we could solve them?

At this point, I have no clue what to do. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO community.. I think that this question should be asked by the second developer so that they can tell us about the debugging details

Comment: Yeah... but we were in a discord call together and were debugging together. So I can tell you what all we did: We changed the code from using the mDatabase only to using the instance, we tried changing read and write permissions to true, we then tried to put in print statements and noticed that it never when inside the ValueEventListener, however it was able to print out the reference to the database, which was the right link.

Answer (score 0):

Being added as an owner on the project doesn't guarantee that they have the same permissions from inside your project. a project owner simply has permission to use the web console in firebase which has essentially admin-sdk priviledes while the client depends on Firebase auth users.

In this situation, you have to ensure that your other client on your friend's setup has the same login credentials available to it depending on your actions.

- From within your project folder, this requires the firebase project to be logged in with their project credentials using `firebase login`.
- For testing within the app, you may need to share the same testing account.
- If using a personal email within the app, ensure it has all the relevant flags that enable that user to behave as an admin, `custom claims` and `security rules`